# How do I select a set of Blender elements with a common characteristic?

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

I'd like to be able to select in one operation a set of blender elements (vertices, edges, and faces) with a common characteristic, for example a certain value (or range of values) on a particular axis, or a set of elements which lie a specified distance from the designated pivot point. I know some particular instances can be accomplished by existing tools, for example, going to front or side view, one could use box select to obtain a set of vertices with a certain value of Z-axis co-ordinate, but I'm asking more generally. For example, to be able to select all edges of a certain length, or faces with a certain area.

Answer (score 1):

For a mesh in edit mode with

- vertex selection see the menu Select Similar.
- face selection see the menu Select Similar Area
- edge selection menu Select Similar Length
- Many other options

[image]

Circle Select with the Letter C Selects a circular distance in 2D in many, not all, cases.
To select a ring, first select objects by radius A, then second scroll mouse wheel to smaller radius B, then press Middle Mouse to button to remove the middle.  A minus B (A - B)

Still in mesh edit mode, if you are making a selection repeatedly, consider creating a vertex group for that selection.

Suggestion.  For Objects only.  If you are making the same selection many times. Consider Grouping those objects and thus select group.  Or more drastically create a common parent and select children.

Comment: Circle select (C-key) selects all of the elements within the current diameter setting of the tool; I'm wanting to select only the elements that lie on the circumference of the tool.